# Windows Phone 8.1 Signed Enterprise App not working as expected

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8.1, code-signing

I'm trying to deploy a Windows Phone 8.1 Application via Enterprise distribution.
For this I'm using `BuildMDILAPPX.ps1`to sign the application with a symantec certificate.

The Application works as expected when deployed via Visual Studio or via Application Distribution.

However once I try to install the application generated by `BuildMDILAPPX.ps1` certain functionality (Database with SQLite) seems to produce an error, as the application behaves differently (e.g. stuck on screen).

Is there a way to debug this application via Visual Studio, or any other way?

Or is it possible to deactivate optimization via `BuildMDILAPPX.ps1`

Thanks for your help,
Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using Toast Notifications to display which line was executed or to display variables.

Not a clean solution, but it worked.